# Ruby: Saving two models in one post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails, coming from .NET, in fact this is the first Ruby project I've worked on so I'm still working out how things are approached.

I'll start with the structure for my problem: I have a **Project table**, and an **Image** table. There is also a **ProjectImage** table which as you'd guess has a `project_id` and an `image_id`. As a user, when I create a project, in the new/edit view, I'd like to be able to select any images I'd like to upload too (I'd like to enforce at least one image being selected too, but perhaps that is another question).

I'd like to think this is possible, as it's fairly simple to do in `.NET`, I'd just have a **ViewModel** representing the `Project` and at least one required `image_id`. However, my understanding of Rails isn't enough to be able to see a direct replication of approach in Rails.

I've looked around, and from my understanding I'm perhaps not approaching this the right way, so my question is, is this possible, am I approaching it incorrectly, if so, what approach is conventional with Rails?

Comment: Checkout the [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) gem, it's the trending attachments gem for Ruby/Rails right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up your form this way

```
<%= form_for :project, :html=> {:multipart=>true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= file_field_tag :images, :multiple => true, :name => 'images[]' %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

then in your controller, you have your project attributes in `params[:project]` (just a title in this case) while `params[:images]` will be an array of uploaded images.

There are of course some good gems for this purpose, like [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) but as you said your understanding isn't enough, I figured you might want to get a grip of it before you start taking shortcuts.

For the **ProjectImage** table, if you don't need additional information stored in the relation itself, you should instead add a project_id column to your images table, and then let an image `belong_to :project` and a project `has_many :images`

Comment: What are the good gems? I'd like to try first with your example, just to develop my understanding and then implement it using a gem.

Comment: Also, I have other entities that share a relationship with the Image table, hence the ProjectImage table

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of Rails from one newbie to another.

I suggest having a look at carrierwave. I found it very useful for implementing a image upload into my models. It can also use imagemagick to make sure your users don't upload images to big and there can also be alot of validation to make sure your database isn't overloaded.

You can find the github here, feel free to ask if you have any questions on it:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

There is also an older gem which alot of people use which you can find here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Also not sure you need a projectimage table as you just need to add a column to your project table and an image will be stored there as a hash for the filepath and referenced by project or user.

You can see a railscast for carrierwave here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the advice!